# I can't find mvc5 and web api template in vs2013

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I know how to create a mvc5 or web API project.But I can't find these templates.
New Project > Templates > Visual C# > Web > ASP.NET Web Application > Press OK >
There are only three templates. empty,webforms and other one.
I make sure the framework version is 4.5.1 
Someone please help me solve the problem.
[image]

Comment: Have you included the Microsoft ASP.NET MVC Nuget package?

Comment: Sorry, how could I include the Micrisoft ASP.NET MVC package?Isn't it ought to be added in the solution?@StephenMuecke

Comment: Go to Tools -> Nuget Package Manager -> Manage Nuget Packages for Solution, then check that its installed (and the Web API package)

Comment: @StephenMuecke - How can he do that when he hasn't created his solution yet?

Comment: @Luke - what's "other one"?

Comment: When you select Visual C# > Web > ASP.NET Web Application, select the MVC checkbox in the next step.

Comment: @ErikFunkenbusch, Because I didn't read the question properly :)

Comment: @ErikFunkenbusch I've uploaded the screenshot of the three templates I mentioned before

Comment: @Luke - it sounds like you have something corrupted in your installation.. I would reinstall Visual Studio.  Make sure you also apply Update 3 (the latest, which just came out).

Answer (score 0):

Try installing [ASP.NET and Web Tools for Visual Studio 2013](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=39365)
Don't forget to restart Visual Studio afterwards.